# AWS Secrets and Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, .net, aws-secrets-manager

I'm currently using AWS Secrets Manager and I have setup a profile and I can see the config and credentials files in c:\users \ {name} \ .aws.

I'm using visual Studio 2022 on a .net framework version 4.8. The strange thing is that when I call it GetSecretValue from one solution it works fine and I'm able to get AWS Secrets.

```
        using (var client = new AmazonSecretsManagerClient(RegionEndpoint.USEast1))
        {
            GetSecretValueRequest request = new GetSecretValueRequest();
            request.SecretId = name;
            request.VersionStage = "AWSCURRENT";
            var result = client.GetSecretValue(request);
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyCustomObject>(result.SecretString);
        }
```

But when I create a new solution with .net framework version 4.8 it is not picking up the profile. The error keeps coming back:

Unable to get IAM Security Credentials from EC2 Instance MetaData Service.

Answer (score 0):

It was a mistake on my part I had to add the proper config to appsettings:

```
<add key="AWSProfileName" value="my Profile Name"/>
<add key="AWSRegion" value="us-east-1"/>
```